# How to select Facebook Send Dialog with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, message, send

I initialize a Facebook Send Dialog using the following code as stated in the [Official Facebook Developers Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog):

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send'
});
```

I know it is not allowed, but I need to send a message on the user's behalf. How can I select the Send Dialog through jQuery and click the send button programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="send">Send</a>

$("#send").click(function(){

    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    });

});
```